# Animation freezes after a number of frames after upgrading Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I recently updated my matplotlib python package to version 2.2.0, and now some previously working code to save an animation does not work. Instead of saving an animation, the code freezes at a certain iteration number. It becomes unresponsive to interrupts and throws a PyEval_RestoreThread fatal error when I manage to close the command window.

I am using Enthought Canopy. The code still works as normal with other versions of python and matplotlib.

I can replicate the problem with this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

SIZE = 128
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ims = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(SIZE, SIZE))

i = 0
def update_animation(*args):
    global i
    i = i + 1
    image = np.random.rand(SIZE, SIZE)
    ims.set_data(image)
    print "Iteration "+str(i)

F_NAME = "anim_test.mp4"
NUM_ITERS = 1000
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=6, bitrate=500)
anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update_animation,frames=NUM_ITERS,blit=False, repeat=False, interval=200)
anim.save(F_NAME, writer=FFwriter)    
print "saved animation to " + F_NAME
```

Changing the bitrate parameter changed the number of the frame the program halts at. For bitrate=500, it halts around frame 46.

How can I stop pyplot freezing before all frames can be saved?

**EDIT**
My system details:
Python 2.7.6 64bit Enthought Canopy
Windows 8
8GB RAM
ffmpeg version N-79075-ga7b8a6e

Comment: For me it stops at frame 209. If I set the bitrate to `-1` (the default) it goes to 220.

Comment: I am now getting some variation in the final frame number for the same bitrate. It freezes at about frame 60 when I set bitrate to `-1`.

Comment: I reported this issue on GitHub, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10729

Comment: Could you add your operating system, python version, ffmpeg version either here or on that issue? That would help finding the cause of this undesired behaviour.

Comment: If the ffmpeg cli tool is being executed, can you capture and share its log?

Comment: I have added my system details above

Comment: Here are the results from adding `-report` to the ffmpeg cli arguments https://pastebin.com/pZTc6Rsk